# Mongoid: why fetching count is slower than fetching documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I noticed a strange behavior. It might be mongoid or mongodb, I am not sure, but Counting documents is slower than fetching the documents. Here are the queries I fired:

```
Institution.all.any_of(:portaled_at.ne => nil).any_of(portaled: true).order_by(:portaled_at.desc).count
# mongodb query and timing as per mongoid logs, 
# times are consistent over multiple runs
# MONGODB (236ms) db['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"institutions", "query"=>{"$or"=>[{:portaled_at=>{"$ne"=>nil}}, {:portaled=>true}]}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
# MONGODB (245ms) db['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"institutions", "query"=>{"$or"=>[{:portaled_at=>{"$ne"=>nil}}, {:portaled=>true}]}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)

Institution.all.any_of(:portaled_at.ne => nil).any_of(portaled: true).order_by(:portaled_at.desc).to_a
# mongodb query and timing as per mongoid logs
# times are not so consistent over multiple runs,
# but consistently much lower than count query
# MONGODB (9ms) db['institutions'].find({"$or"=>[{:portaled_at=>{"$ne"=>nil}}, {:portaled=>true}]}).sort([[:portaled_at, :desc]])
# MONGODB (18ms) db['institutions'].find({"$or"=>[{:portaled_at=>{"$ne"=>nil}}, {:portaled=>true}]}).sort([[:portaled_at, :desc]])
```

I believe indexes are not used by mongodb for `$and` and `$or` queries, but just so if it matters, I have a sparse index on `portaled_at` in descending order. Out of around 200,000 documents only around 50-60 have portaled_at set.

- rails 3.2.12
- mongoid 2.6.0
- mongodb 2.2.3

This is against my common sense and if anybody can explain what is going on I would really appreciate it.

Comment: One is running a database command http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/, and the other a query. There's a documented issue (that will be fixed in 2.4) against very slow `count` calls. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the two are running through different subsystems in MongoDB (one is using [runCommand](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) and the other the standard query engine), the specific issue in this case is very likely a known issue in the current version of MongoDb.

The quick summary is that counting without fetching is extremely [slow](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752) as MongoDb is doing a lot of extra work that often isn't necessary. It's been fixed in the development branch, so it should be in 2.4 when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Mongo defaults to not counting records using only indexes. However, if you construct a query correctly, Mongo will count from the index. The trick is to only fetch the fields that are in the index, and you have to specify a query.

In Mongo Shell:

`db.MyCollection.find({"_id":{$ne:''}},{"_id":1}).count()`

You can check with the explain method:

`db.MyCollection.find({"_id":{$ne:''}},{"_id":1}).explain()`

Which will include `"indexOnly" : true` in the output.

And similarly the command can be executed via the Moped driver directly like so:

`Mongoid::Sessions.default.command(:count => "MyCollection", :query=>{"_id"=>{"$ne"=>""}}, :fields => {:_id=>1})`

Which, in my benchmarks (on my live data, YMMV) is about 100x faster than simply doing `MyMongoidDocumentClass.count`

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this quickly through the Mongoid gem.